# I want to use Get /v1.2/products REST API of Uber in android

Tags: uber-api

I want to use Uber in my app by using its Rest API, and when I hit the same from Postman and i will get the same error every time

```
{
  "message": "No authentication provided.",
  "code": "unauthorized"
}
```

after entering the same request as given sample on the Uber Developers Site. you can also check the same here:

[this is the link](http://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/products-get)

And I am attaching here the pic of my request.

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZbpz.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Authorization header, replace `server_token` with `Token`.

So your example header has:

```
Authorization:server_token SERVER_TOKEN
```

replace that with:

```
Authorization: Token SERVER_TOKEN
```

Comment: But have you do the whole process of **Uber Rest Api** Integration. As i am looking forward to get  **OAuth 2.0** to authorise user but after getting the successful response as Login Page , i am unable to move forward even with correct credential i get nothing.                                                                     can you please help me out that how we can authorise our app when the user to allow access. [link](https://d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net/developer.uber.com/_static/images/tutorial/connect@2x.png)